# Como fazer calculo com números em uma String em C#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma string que o Arduíno manda para minha aplicação através da porta serial com o seguinte formato:

> variável = #valor de distancia de ultrassom##valor de distancia de ultrassom#...(com 10 amostras iguais a esta).

Preciso separar somente os números desta string, somá-las entre si, calcular uma média simples sobre estes valores armazenado esta média em uma variável e mostrar em um textbox mostrar o valor.
Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço.

Answer (score 5):

Simples.

```
string str = "#10##10##50##100#";

var listValores = str.Split('#').ToList();
listValores.RemoveAll(x => x == "");

decimal soma = 0;
foreach(var v in listValores)
{
    decimal vlr;
    decimal.TryParse(v, out vlr);

    soma += vlr;
}

decimal media = soma / listValores.Count;

WriteLine($"Soma: {soma} - Média: {media}");

textBox.Text = media;
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nc5JPn)

Comment: `Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+"); Match m = r.Match(str);`

Comment: Ah não, regex não! :P Cria uma resposta, é uma alternativa boa.

Comment: A sua é mais rápida, fora que seria igual a  sua, alterando apenas a 3, 4 linha, vou manter como comentário, apenas como alternativa, para quem gosta :D

Answer (score -3):

```
var numero = "#10##10##50##100#";

var splits = numero.Split('#');
List<double> list = new ();

foreach(var i in splits)
{
   Int16.TryParse(i, out short number);
    if (number > 0)
         list.Add(Convert.ToInt16(i));
}

Console.WriteLine(list.Sum());
Console.WriteLine(list.Average());
```